# Should I put main method in superclass or subclass in Java

Tags: java

If a class has inheritance in a Java program, do I need to put main method in the superclass or subclass? Many programs put the main method in different positions. Can anybody tell me how to do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: u need to out in the sub class if u want the methods and fields(private fields and methods) of subclass to working with.

Comment: @AkhilDev Unless the subclass methods and fields are private, you do not need to put it in the subclass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it might be best to have a simple class whose sole dedicated purpose is to contain the `static main` method.  It simple and clear.

Your main method would then get things started by creating the initial objects from your program.

Comment: This emphasizes that ur code can logically support multiple applications each with their own `main` method entry point class.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a new dedicated class, let's say Launcher, with a main method, instantiate your classes there, and manage any unexpected exceptions:

```
public class Luncher{

  public static void main(String args){
    //insert argument checking logic

    try{
      new MyClass.executeLogic(someArguments);
    }catch(Exception e){
      //insert exception handling logic here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you where you'll put main method, but I'd just put it into new class with only one method, `static Main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 1):

You would want to put a `main()` method in a place where you control, or drive all of the action of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends, But usually main method put in sub class. There is quite big difference between in inheritance and shadowing. But you can put it subclass or super class. Remember main method is static.

Answer (score -1):

We have to put the main method inside the main class only. Then whether you make it a parent class or sub class doesn't matter, It will work fine, But the main method needs to be inside the main class else compiler will throw error.